# Why are these notes written this way and how should it be played on the piano?

Tags: piano, notation

Self-taught player here with very rudimentary knowledge of theory so please go easy on me! The notes highlighted in yellow are confusing me a bit, as they are the same note, but one is a minim and the other a crochet.

[image]

I feel like I should be playing the minim and hold it while I play the the next notes. Is this correct?

If yes, why is that same note written twice on the bass clef, as two seperate notes (a minim and a crochet)?

Comment: At least [related question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/63743/2600).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you are correct.  You hold the E (actually I'm guessing that's an E flat) and then play the next notes.

Why?  Because there are multiple parts in the bass clef.  One of them goes low F crotchet followed by high E flat minim.  The other goes low F crotchet, high E flat crotchet and then the F and A crotchet together.  That also explains why there are two stems on that first bottom F.