# Violin - Sheet music notation for playing the same note at the same time

Tags: notation, sheet-music, fingering, violin, double-stops

On the violin you can play a double stop where you are playing 4th finger on the D string (A note) while playing the open A string. This means that you are playing the A note on both strings. How would you write this on sheet music?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, like this:

[image]

The noteheads may be shunted apart if other voices are present.

Comment: What is that type of notehead called?

Comment: That is the regular notehead. The upward and downward stems follow the convention for writing multiple parts, or voices, on the same staff. Google for multiple voices or multiple parts notation for examples. Alternatively, this question https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/76880/why-are-these-notes-written-this-way-and-how-should-it-be-played-on-the-piano/76881#76881 shows another example.